# Shopify Storefront API for new Sales Channel Checkout Problem

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

i am creating a custom storefront alongside the standard Shopify store. Now when I create a checkout and open the webURL from the response everything works as well. But here is the problem:
When the customer clicks on the logo in the checkout, he is not redirected back to my custom storefront, but to the standard Shopify store. Is it possible to solve this problem?

All already read the documentary.